# How to use the proximity sensor as a way to dim the phone screen?

Tags: android, proximity

I know I should have code here but this is one of the cases where I dont have any.

I am wondering how to get my phone to dim with out the use of an object in the proximity sensor... So if that made no sense I'm trying to make the proximity sensor's role switch so that it dims when the screen is in light.

If the example helps more I could be trying to make the screen more bright automatically using the sensor as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proximity sensor is used to detect the devices proximity to something, not the ambient light. You want to use the light sensor for that. However, you can use the proximity sensor to dim or switch off the screen when it is held close to the user's face, like the call app does on most phones.